# Изменение массива в Dictionary

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Есть код:

```
class test
{
    //variables
    internal Dictionary<string, int[]> MyDict = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();

    //construction
    public test()
    {
        MyDict.Add("test", new int[0]);
    }

    //add method
    internal void AddNewElement(string dictString, int a)
    {
        //copy
        int[] values = MyDict[dictString];
        //resize
        Array.Resize(ref values, values.Length + 1);
        //add new value
        values[values.Length - 1] = a;
        //save ?!
        MyDict[dictString] = values;
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как бы Вы реализовали метод `AddNewElement()`?

Comment: Чем Вас не устраивает существующая реализация?

Comment: не *//copy*, a *//get reference*

Comment: @Igor, хочу узнать мнение более опытных людей, т.к мне кажется это не самый оптимальный метод.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Массивы -- это "статическая" структура данных, не подразумевающая изменение размера (т.е. добавление и удаление элементов).

Используйте список:

```
Dictionary<string, List[]> MyDict = new Dictionary<string, List[]>();

internal void AddNewElement(string dictString, int a)
{
    List[] values = MyDict[dictString];
    values.Add(a);
    // стоит однако проверять, что список для такого ключа уже существует
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, в самом начале исключил List, из-за скорости работы, но может оказаться, что метод `Array.Resize()` занимает больше времени чем `.Add()`, верно?

Comment: В общем случае нет, потому что списки время от времени тоже ресайзятся. Но т.к. они ресайзятся с запасом (чего вы не делали), то да, на серии добавлений будут быстрее. Но даже если вы тоже сделаете ресайз с запасом, список все равно логичнее использовать. Разница в быстродействии копеечная.

Answer (score 1):

```
class IntArraysDictionary
{
    private Dictionary<String, Int32[]> _dictionary;

    public IntArraysDictionary()
    {
        this._dictionary = new Dictionary<String, Int32[]>();

    }

    public Int32[] Add(String key, Int32[] intArray)
    {
        if(this._dictionary.Keys.Contains(key))
        {
            this._dictionary[key] = intArray;
            return intArray;
        }

        this._dictionary.Add(key, intArray);
        return intArray;
    }
}
```

Есть такой вариант. Обратите внимание на именование класса, методов и переменных, а также на то, что инициализацию всех полей класса (его состояние) лучше производить непосредственно в конструкторе.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но в Вашем методе каждый раз добавляется новая запись в Dictionary, а мне надо записывать значение в массив, который храниться в Dictionary

Comment: Внимание на синтаксис и названия переменных, обратил. Очень легко читается, буду стремиться к такому стилю. Спасибо